# MKAnnotationView UIView or UIImage

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, png, mkannotationview, paintcode

I have a map with many (>500) custom annotation views. Currently I am using a UIView that implements the `drawRect:` method which then draws the annotations view with `UIBezierPath` and other `vectorish` methods (from PaintCode). I have noticed however that when loading the map it sometimes takes quite a bit of time for the pins to show up. Would it be better to use a transparent PNG or SVG? What is less memory and processor intensive? What is the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading an image file using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` seems less processor intensive than calling `drawRect` and its associated `UIBezierPath` drawing methods for each `UIView`.

`drawRect` is also called whenever the view is required to update, so it may be called many times.

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` on the other hand, caches images, which is another optimization.